# Looping with many fors

Tags: python

Im trying to run code for a support vector machine with many different parameters which would result in looping my code for 284 times. When I use the 6 required for loops in a simple code and just print i=i+1 every loop everything works fine.

But when I try to run the for loops with my code I get a weird error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
1.61 Seconds to train SVC...
  File "C:/Users/Felix/PycharmProjects/SupportVectorMachine/AccuracyTest.py", line 102, in <module>
Test Accuracy of SVC =  0.9333
    for ppc in pix_per_cell:
My SVC predicts:  [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The error message is for some reason in between some print commands?
Here is an example of the for loops im using

```
cspace = ['RGB','HLS','YUV','HSV','YCrCb','LUV']
orients = [9,10,11]
cells_per_blocks = [1,2]
cchan = [0,1,2,'ALL']
pix_per_cell = [8,16]
i=0
for a in range(3):    
    for cs in cspace:
        for ori in orients:
            for cpb in cells_per_blocks:
                for cc in cchan:
                    for ppc in pix_per_cell:
                        print('Cspace:' + str(cs))
                        print('orient:' + str(ori))
                        print('cellsperblock:' + str(cpb))
                        print('cchan:' + str(cc))
                        print('pixpercell' + str(ppc))
                        print('_____________________')
```

Any help would be appreciated
Cheers,
Felix

Comment: I don't think you're posting the part of code that is causing the error. The above code works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah that kinda is my problem. The upper code is working without inserting my code just fine but when i try to loop the training for my SupportVectorMachine with different parameters (thats what the for loops are there) it stops with the mentioned error after 2 out of 284 iterations :(

Answer (score 1):

You haven't exactly given all of the code/context, but I"d guess you think pix_per_cell is an iterable but when you get your error message pix_per_cell is an int and not a list of ints.

Comment: I'm sorry but i gotta admit that i dont fully understand your answer. Isnt pix_per_cell supposed to be an int ? I mean my code uses it as an int as a parameter.

Comment: I don't know what's *supposed* to happen in your code, but if you try to iterate over something in a for loop (for variable in iterable), then it needs to be an iterable, which an int type isn't.
In your code that you posted this isn't the case, but I think this is happening somewhere in part of the code that you haven't posted.

Comment: Thanks alot! That helped me find the error. I have used the same variable (pix_per_cell) inside my code and it was overwritten :)

Comment: If it answered your question please upvote the answer :)